# Python on Linux: How to *immediately* move files to USB to avoid issues from OS not syncing and the USB suddenly being pulled

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I have a Python script using shutil to move files from an internal folder to any present USB drives automatically.  Even after the script closes, it seems that the OS does not always actually move the files to the USB drive until sometime later.  My research suggests the OS does this delay for wear leveling purposes, but I am not certain that's the real explanation.  Is there something I can add (ideally to my Python script or tied to it) so that the write will actually be executed immediately?  Perhaps a different way to move the file, some way to demand an immediate sync, verifying the files were really moved, or doing some follow-on action that would require the OS to truly execute the move?

To be clear, I am not talking about problems from pulling the USB while the write is actively happening.  The files are in total not many KB in size and I am seeing the problem even when the drive is pulled 40+ seconds later. The drives aren't blinking.  I am not seeing partial writes where some files are moved and others aren't that would suggest I'm interrupting it midway through.  Even if this was the issue, I think my question is still a valid question.

Background: I am running Raspbian Buster desktop version and Python 3.7.3 on a Pi4.   I want to run this Pi without keyboard or monitor so that no user intervention is required to pull the drives or put in replacement ones.  I have to run the desktop despite there being no monitor or else the Pi will not automount USB drives, but that is a separate issue.  I am a noob, so especially thorough explanations would be particularly appreciated.

Comment: `fileobj.flush()` then `os.fsync(fileobj.fileno())` before close may do it.

Comment: And possibly `os.system("sync")` to be absolutely sure :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo - yes! Since "sync" gets all the files in the file system, it could be done at the end of the move job, for instance.

Comment: I've been trying to test the os.system("sudo sync") but it's hard to tell if it's working.  I also implemented a check to see if the file size of the copy and original were the same, but that has failed at least once.  I am copying the files with shutil.copy(source) so I am not sure what goes into the place of the fileobj in your example.  All the examples I see of fsync and flush are under the construct open(filename, "w")...  Could you please explain a little more in detail?  Thank you!

Comment: FYI, "immediate" isn't possible, since a "move" is really a copy since you are crossing a file system boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tdelaney said in their comment, the thorough-to-the-point-of-overkill way is to call `flush()` on the file object, then `os.fsync()` on its file descriptor, which since Raspbian is based on the Linux kernel shouldn't return until the buffers are flushed.

But if you're using one of the `shutil.copy`* functions, you don't have a file object to call those on, so you can just call out to `os.system("sync")`.

But note that even if the kernel is dusting its hands and saying "yup, flushed those buffers", the data could still be working its way through the device driver internals and not yet physically written to the media. You can't get a 100% guarantee that it's all the way through unless you're manually driving the USB logic, but the next best thing is adding a command to unmount the file system.

The problem is that code running from the USB stick can't unmount the filesystem containing itself, so if your Python is on the stick, it can't do the unmount. You can do it manually from the command line, though. Just `umount /path/to/usb/stick` should do it.

Comment: Can you explain a bit how to call flush() or os.fsync() ?  All the examples I see first require opening the file with open(filename, "w") but these files are already written.  Sorry I am a bit of a noob, so a little more explanation would help.  Is there some kind of check function I can do to see that they truly exist at the destination in full form?  Are you saying os.system("sudo sync") does nothing or that it's redundant with os.fsync()?  Thank you!

Comment: Edited to mention that case. You did say you were using `shutil`...

Comment: For completeness, you also need to unmount the USB drive before pulling it, which should not complete until all pending writes have completed.

Comment: I am using the os.system("sudo sync") solution which seems to work.  The only time it doesn't is for the one file that is actually mid-transit when the USB is yanked.  TO be clear, I run `shutil.copy` in a try block, then `os.system("sudo sync")` and then I do `os.path.getsize` on both the original and copy. The file that's midtransit seems to pass all three checks despite obviously never arriving..  Other than that case, it seems to work.

Comment: FWIW, you don't need `sudo` to run `sync`, even if you weren't on a Pi.

Comment: Mark, I thought sync would only do it for the current user's files.  Can you explain why?  https://www.computerhope.com/unix/sync.htm

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=56171

Comment: thanks!  That thread suggests that the command should be `sync; sync` because the second wont return until the first completes, but that seems weird

Comment: I suppose the getsize check I was doing fails bc the OS thinks it knows the size of the file it just moved and never checks the USB to get the real facts?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu and I had to call `os.system("sync;")` as @rfii mentioned. If I don't have the semicolon, it will hang the python script.

Comment: That must have been a coincidence, @beeeliu. The semicolon makes no difference in the behavior; you need one between multiple commands in the same line, but at the end of the line it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I have a new idea. Perhaps after an attempt is made to move a file onto the USB, a meaningless atomic function could be used to change the file on the USB.  Something that would require the file to actually be written to the USB.  Then the program could check that it happened.  Would renaming the file on the USB to add a dash or something work? So, program tries to move file ABC to the USB.  Then it tries to rename the file on the USB to ABC-.  Lastly it checks that there is a file on the USB called ABC-.  Would that work?